# When does cellForItemAtIndexPath get called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Can you make an assumption as to when `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will get called? I have a `UICollectionView` where each cell is the same size as the collection view. Most cells get dequeued just as they become visible. Sometimes, however, `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` gets called not only for the next index path but also for the one after that (at the same time). For example, if I'm currently seeing index 5, and start scrolling, but 6 and 7 will get dequeued.

Is the way `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` gets called documented somewhere, or are we not supposed to assume any recurrent functionality?

Comment: As far as I know you can't say anything other than"when a cell is needed".

Comment: @DanielLarsson how did you get around this issue? I facing the same exact thing full size cells now

Comment: @LanceSamaria you can set collectionView's `isPrefetchingEnabled` to `false` so it does not try to load the cells in advance.

Comment: @CyberMew from my understanding, multiple cells can still be dequeued simultaneously even when `isPrefetchingEnabled` is set to `false`, we just can't assume that they all will. The docs state that *"When false, the cells are requested as they are needed for display, often with multiple cells being requested in the same render loop."*

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, they are dequeued as needed for display. If you scroll really fast and it decides that the current render loop needs to show x amount of cells on screen instead of just one, then yes those exact x amount of necessary cells will be dequeued and not a single more. The system will not prefetch cells in advance in anticipation and dequeue them when the prefetch flag is false. The purpose of prefetching is to improve performance while scrolling. I am happy to be corrected if my understanding is incorrect though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or are we not supposed to assume any recurrent functionality

That is correct. I can name some calls you can make that will *cause* it to be called, but that's not the point. The point is that your job is to be ready to answer this question correctly and quickly at any moment. The runtime calls you as often as it thinks might be necessary in order to display the current set of cells and in order to make future scrolling as smooth as possible. As some poet says: "That's all you know and you need to know."

Comment: Also, are you aware that iOS 10 has a collection view cell "prefetching" feature? So this is _expected_ behavior.